# Django. Using variable in a Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a query

```
variable3 = "Field3"
variable_gte = "flowrate__gte"
x = mytable.objects.filter(Q((variable_gte, variable2))).order_by(variable3)[0:5]
z = x[0].Field3
```

How can I call this last value `z` using `variable3`, something similar to `z = x[0].variable3`
If it is impossible, I will need to use if/else condition:

```
if variable3 = "Field3":
    z = x[0].Field3
else:
    ....
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**`getattr(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
variable3 = 'Field3'
variable_gte = 'flowrate__gte'
x = mytable.objects.filter(
    Q((variable_gte, variable2))
).order_by(variable3)[0:5]

z = getattr(x[0], variable3)
```

If you write `getattr(x, 'y')`, this is equivalent to `x.y`, so you can pass a string with the name of the attribute and obtain the attribute of that name.

It however does not make much sense to first slice, and then obtain the first item. You can remove the `…[0:5]` part.

Comment: Thank you for a high quality answer. It solved my problem.